# How to fix this kind of problem?

Tags: font-size, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<br /><br /><br />
<div style="line-height:150%">
<span style="display:block;font-size:240%;">test</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

First double click on the text `test`,then it's highlighted,

then you can see via firebug that the `<span>` it's in is shorter than the text itself.

How to make the `span` automatically grow with the text?

Comment: Shouldn't that go to Doctype?

Answer (score 4):

Try changing `line-height` to `1.5`

Comment: `line-height: 150%` will make it 1.5 times whatever the line-height of the `div` is, and fix it for the children as well, despite the children's `font-size` being bigger. `line-height: 1.5` means it'll be 1.5 times of the whatever each element's `font-size` is - for your example, the `line-height` of the span is `2.4 * 1.5 * <font-size of div>`

Comment: K Prime is correct. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040788/whats-the-difference-between-line-height1-5-and-line-height150-in-css/2040799#2040799

Answer (score 1):

This is your original code:

```
<div style="line-height: 150%;">
 <span style="display: block; font-size: 240%;">Test</span>
</div>
```

This sets the `line-height` of all the elements inside the `div` to 150%. This percentage is relative to their **computed** font size.
The `span` inherits the `font-size` of the `div`, and the `line-height` is calculated based on that.
You set the `font-size` of the `span` to 24 times its inherited size, but the `line-height` is unaffected.

**In short:** `line-height: 150%` will take 150% of the element’s *computed* font size to compute the line height, which is equivalent to multiply it by 1.5.

---

As mentioned, using `line-height: 1.5;` instead fixes that behavior:

```
<div style="line-height: 1.5;">
 <span style="display: block; font-size: 240%;">Test</span>
</div>
```

This triggers the recalculation of the `line-height` based on the new font size.
It sets the `line-height` of all the elements inside the `div` to 1.5 times. This percentage is relative to their **actual** font size.
The `span` inherits the `font-size` of the `div`.
You set the `font-size` of the `span` to 2.4 times its inherited size, and the new `line-height` is calculated based on that.

**In short:** `line-height: 1.5` (without units) will multiply the element’s *actual* font size by `1.5` to compute the line height.

Comment: Nope. Its computed `line-height` is `150%`, but its `font-size` is just inherited (`100%`), then reset to `240%`. `240%` (`font-size`) > `150%` (`line-height`) — that’s why, in this case, you should use the dynamic `line-height: 1.5` instead of the static `line-height: 150%`. [Terminology courtesy of K Prime ;)]