# What's the difference between line-height:1.5 and line-height:150% in css?

Tags: css

Anyone knows about it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Short version: `line-height: 150%` is static, `line-height: 1.5` is dynamic. The effect is more evident on inheriting elements. An example:

HTML

```
<div style="font-size: 12px">
    <span style="font-size: 24px">test</span>
</div>
```

This CSS

```
div { line-height: 150%; } /* Computed line-height: 18px (150% * 12px) */
span { }                   /* Computed line-height: 18px (inherited directly) */
```

As opposed to this:

```
div { line-height: 1.5 }   /* Computed line-height: 18px (1.5 * 12px) */
span { }                   /* Computed line-height: 36px (1.5 * 24px) */
```

You may read more at the [CSS2 specs page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height)

Comment: I would give +2 if I could, it took me too much time to come up with clear sentences to explain it

Comment: I think 150% is calculated by inherited font size,but 1.5 is calculated by computed font size.Is that right?

Comment: It's more like 150% is just inherited directly, but 1.5 recalculaltes each time

Answer (score 11):

<strike>Both are equivalent.</strike>

`line-height: 1.5` (without units) will mutiply the element's font size by `1.5` to compute the line height.

`line-height: 150%` will take `150%` of the element's **computed** font size to compute the line height, which is equivalent to multiply it by `1.5`.

> The three rules in the example below have the same resulting line height:

```
div { line-height: 1.2; font-size: 10pt }     /* number */
div { line-height: 1.2em; font-size: 10pt }   /* length */
div { line-height: 120%; font-size: 10pt }    /* percentage */
```

Now let’s have a look at [the question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040694/how-to-fix-this-kind-of-problem).

I reproduced the two cases:

1. http://gregory.pakosz.fr/stackoverflow/2040694-number.html
2. http://gregory.pakosz.fr/stackoverflow/2040694-percentage.html

In 1), the parent's div's `line-height` is set to `1.5` multiplied the div's actual font size. This property is inherited and recomputed for the child `span` because you changed its actual font size.

In 2), the parent's div's `line-height` is set to `150%` of the div's computed font size. Then the computed font size of the `span` is inherited from the `div` therefore `150%` of this inherited computed font size leads to the same value.

**As @K Prime summed up, the take away is likely: `line-height: 150%` is static, `line-height: 1.5` is dynamic**

References:

- [10.8 Line height calculations: the 'line-height' and 'vertical-align' properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height) (CSS2)

Comment: No,they are not.See my previous post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040694/how-to-fix-this-kind-of-problem

Comment: Isn't "element's font size" and "element's computed font size" the same thing?

Comment: No they're not. It took me a while to upload the files, in the mean time other answers are perfectly fine as well

Answer (score 1):

```
line-height:  normal | 

<number>| 

<length>| 

<percentage>
```

From **[line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/line-height)**

```
<number>
```

The used value is this unitless  multiplied by the element's font size. The computed value is the same as the specified . In most cases this is is the preferred way to set line-height with no unexpected results in case of inheritance.

```
<percentage>
```

Relative to the font size of the element itself. The computed value is this percentage multiplied by the element's computed font size.